# Discord.py Not showing how many servers it is in

Tags: python

My code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def servers(ctx):
  await ctx.send( f"I'm in {str(len(client.guilds))} servers")
```

When I use the command it says: `I'm in 0 servers`, but it's not in 0 servers.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code.

There is no error in this code and it runs as it should be. I tried this code:

#### With str()

```
@bot.command()
async def servers(ctx):
  await ctx.send( f"I'm in {str(len(client.guilds))} servers")
```

#### Withour str()

```
@bot.command()
async def servers(ctx):
  await ctx.send( f"I'm in {len(client.guilds)} servers")
```

The image below shows how it was executed:
[image: No Error!]

---

I would like to see your whole code first.

Thank You! :)

Comment: I fixed it, the intents should be enabled

Comment: Of course. I forgot to mention that. But anyways nice.